# Dismissing of system alerts in XCTests all of a sudden stopped working on iOS 15.6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I had a piece of code that was supposed to dismiss a touch ID alert.

```
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
let allowBtn = springboard.buttons["Cancel"]
if allowBtn.waitForExistence(timeout: 2) {
   allowBtn.tap()
}
```

this code was working fine for years, until it stopped.

The error I'm getting is:

```
[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil (NSInvalidArgumentException)
```

and it happens in the .tap() line.

Basically this is what I see, besides the fact that I'm running on iOS 15. https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5520542106910720

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What did you change before it ‘stopped’? And how is the error related to your code?

Comment: The tests were not touched/edited since the last successful run.

Comment: Have you tried throwing a breakpoint before your test blows up and printing out springboard to see what's in there?

Comment: yes, did try that, but didn't see anything suspicious. The button exists and it's just a regular XCUIElement object.